# Android Fragment Updates

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm attempting to port an existing set of functionality over from another app to the Actionbar/Swipe format that is in new app wizard.

I have individual fragment layouts (which are identical except in name) and have all the buttons included and all working (and tested) via toast statements.

What I can't seem to do is update the textview of the current fragment.  i've tried everything i can think.   I can't decide if i need to do a fragment transaction or if i'm missing something small and chasing my own tail.  I'm getting dizzy, so can someone stop this merry-go-round?

here is part of the fragment coding

```
    public static class DetailFragment extends Fragment {
public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    LayoutInflater _inflater;
    ViewGroup _container;

    public DetailFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int position;
        _inflater = inflater;
        _container = container;
        position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)-1;

        View rootView;
        TextView dummyTextView;
        // Location Database Handler
        //LocationDatabaseHandler locationDatabaseHandler = new LocationDatabaseHandler(getActivity());

        switch (position){
        case 0:

            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_player,container, false);
            dummyTextView= (TextView) rootView .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            // Player
            Button btnTruncateDBPlayerTable = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnTruncateDBPlayerTable);
            Button btnPlayerCount = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnPlayerCount);
            Button btnShowDBPlayerList = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnShowDBPlayerList);
            Button btnShowPlayer = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnShowPlayer);
            Button btnAddContacts = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnAddContacts);
            Button btnAddContact = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnAddContact);

            btnTruncateDBPlayerTable.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override               
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Activity activity = getActivity();
                //android.app.FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();

                ////DummySectionFragment currFragment = (DummySectionFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_main_player);
                //View x =  _inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_player, _container , false);
                //v = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_player, _container , false);
                //TextView myTextView = (TextView) x .findViewById(R.id.section_label);

                if (activity != null) {

                    Toast.makeText(activity, "toast_you_just_clicked_a_fragment btnTruncateDBPlayerTable button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    DetailFragment updateFragment = dFragmentList.get(0);
                    //updateFragment.recieveUpdate("Holy Crap Batman");
                    //myTextView.append("WHOOT");
                }
            }
            });
            btnPlayerCount.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override               
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Activity activity = getActivity();

                    if (activity != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "toast_you_just_clicked_a_fragment btnPlayerCount button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                });
            btnShowDBPlayerList.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override               
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Activity activity = getActivity();

                    if (activity != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "toast_you_just_clicked_a_fragment btnShowDBPlayerList button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                });
            btnShowPlayer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override               
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Activity activity = getActivity();

                    if (activity != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "toast_you_just_clicked_a_fragment btnShowPlayer button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                });
            btnAddContacts.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override               
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Activity activity = getActivity();

                    if (activity != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "toast_you_just_clicked_a_fragment btnAddContacts button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                });
            btnAddContact.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override               
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Activity activity = getActivity();

                    if (activity != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "toast_you_just_clicked_a_fragment btnAddContact button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                });


            break;
```

Comment: So `dummyTextView.setText("Whatever");` doesn't work?

Comment: not on a button push. or 
`        TextView myTextView = (TextView) v .findViewByID(R.id.section_label)
        myTextView.append("WHOOT"); 
`
would work.  it doesn't.  the toast works fine.  I've tried several approaches and you can see by some of the crap leftover.  I'll clean it up when i get it working and then do it all one single way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `dummyTextView` was successfully found previously in `rootView` this will work:

```
btnTruncateDBPlayerTable.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    dummyTextView.setText("Whatever");
    // Toast stuff
});
```

if you wanted to delay finding that TextView for some reason, you could search via the Activity:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.section_label);
textView.setText("Whatever");
```

Doing something like the following as in your commented out code ***will not work***:

```
// in onClick
View x = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_player, _container , false);
TextView myTextView = (TextView) x.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
myTextView.setText("Whatever");
```

By inflating a new layout, you're creating a new TextView as part of it.  You can then find and set the text of that TextView, but since it's not in the layout that's actually displayed, the effect is rather minimal.